# Is there a way to optimize this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-optimization

I have this query I have to automate with AWS Lambda but first I want to optimize it.

It seems legit to me but I have this feeling I can do something to improve it.

```
SELECT q_name, count(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE status = 2
AND DATEDIFF(mi, create_stamp, getdate()) > 1
GROUP BY q_name
```

Comment: Wouldn't create_stamp > getdate() be simpler?

Comment: @SteveFord Yes, it's simpler, but it also does mean something different ...

Comment: what indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I'm not sure about the indexes. I have a problem with the database at the moment. Asked for help and it should be up and running. Will get back soon as it does

Comment: You probably want an index on either `(status, q_name) INCLUDE (create_stamp)` or `(status, create_stamp) INCLUDE (q_name)` depending on the density statistics of `q_name`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only improvement I can see is not to apply a function to your column, because that makes the query unsargable (unable to use indexes). Instead leave the column as it is and calculate the correct cutoff.

```
SELECT q_name, count(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE [status] = 2
--AND DATEDIFF(mi, create_stamp, getdate()) > 1
-- Adjust the logic to meet your requirements, because this is slightly different to what you had
AND create_stamp < DATEADD(minute, -1, getdate())
GROUP BY q_name;
```

Note, while `dateadd` does accept abbreviations for the unit to add, its much clearer to type it in full.

Comment: `datediff(minute,a,b) > 1` means that 2 or more minute boundaries separate `a` and `b`, but that may not have been intentional by OP.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks - yip I realise that, I assumed they would check their logic.

Comment: Yes.  Your query is probably more what they meant: the two dates are separated by more that 60sec.  Not the two dates are separated by at least 61-120 seconds, depending on when you check.